# ios - nav bar on a presented modal controller with storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, modal-dialog, segue

I simply want to add a navigation bar (with some nav bar button) on a presented modal controller with storyboard.

Programmatically with XIBs, it looks like that :

```
SDMapController *mapController = [[SDMapController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDMapController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapController];

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

But I have no idea how to handle it with Storyboard. I guess i have to implement some code on the `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method but since the `destinationController` property of `segue` object is readonly, i don't really know how to do this.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the prepare for segue, only if you want to pass on some data to your presented view controller. Otherwise you can leave it empty. The presenting of the View Controller is from the Interface Builder. You add a navigation controller with it's root view controller and make a segue (ctrl + drag) to the navigation controller. Set the segue type to modal, and give it an ID. You can trigger this segue from code by calling `[self perforSegueWithIdentiefier:@"MySegueID"];`. If you dragged the segue from a button or a table view cell, it will be triggered automatically when you tap on it, without calling this method. As I said, in the `prepareForSegue` method, the `segue.destinationViewController` will bee the presented navigation controller. You can access it's `topViewController` if you need and pass some data to it.

Comment: Oh nice. I tried to embed a navigationController to the first controller, but i don't know why i didn't think about embedding it to the presented controller ... I have a related question : is this a normal situation to have 2 navigation controller on the same "line" in my storyboard ? NavController-->FirstVC--(modal)-->NavController-->SecondVC. Or is this better to place back buttons etc on a toolbar, for example, instead of adding a navcontroller to my presented view ?

Comment: When you are presenting something modally, it is ok to have a new navigation controller in the modal. It is the same as without storyboards, you create a Navigation Controller and present it modally. Like in the code in your question.